# WalletConnect deeplink fails when in production but not locally

Tags: node.js, deep-linking, wallet, wallet-connect

I tried making use of WalletConnect client on my NodeJS client using the following snippet:

```js
import WalletConnect from "@walletconnect/client";

// Create a connector
const connector = new WalletConnect({
  bridge: "https://bridge.walletconnect.org", // Required
});

// Check if connection is already established
if (!connector.connected) {
  // create new session
  connector.createSession();
}
```

The above code snippet works locally in development.
It generates a deeplink uri which I call in other parts of my app and wallets like metamask, trust wallet connect successfully.

```js
QRModal.open(connector.uri)
```

However, when I push the code to fly.io servers, although a deeplink url is generated and this uri still opens the respective wallets, the wallets don't connect to my app.
The only helpful message I get is from trust wallet saying "Failed to Connect"

Comment: did you find any solution? I am also facing same issue mine is working on ngrok tunnel too but not on the prod domain!